# Android - Modify displayed text in ListView items

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a ListView loaded with an `ArrayAdapter<File>` and it shows the file path as the text of each item.

I would like to modify that.

I've read about modifying the `getView()` method from a custom ArrayAdapter but I am not sure if this is the correct path yet.

Any aid?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return to implement your own ArrayAdapter and Override the getView method to return your own view.

Find an example here:

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Comment: I was a really helpful guide to learn how to manage this. Gracias Antonio!